# get (Checkin and Checkout) external file in tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I have Some Project in the team project Collection for example (project A, Project B and Project C) and one or some files external of this project for example X.txt .

I want when Get the project A that file (X.txt) are getting too. or when get project C that file are getting too.

what am i do?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

--Project Collection

```
   -Project A
   -Project B
   -Project C
   -X.txt
```

Your folder level should be such as above. What you want to achieve is impossibel by using TFS UI. You must get twice including Project A and X.txt. It is designed by default.

If you insit on it ,i suggest you can write a batch script which package get(Checkin and Checkout) commond. Run the bath to get Project and X.txt the same time.

Comment: I,m sorry. I did not express correctly!   yes I know but for example we have (the team) some solution (A,B,C,...etc) under the project folder. user use one or two projects and we have one or some file (for example x.txt) that common to all project and put it under the project folder not under the project A. we want when for example user "A" get the his\her project (solution A) he\her can get that file too and change them and checkin, user "B" only need to that file he get his project but he want to have that file but it is not under project B for mapping it. i hop that xplane correctly!

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I have updated my reply. Hope it is helpful for you.